# How can we open my website only chrome browser? Should not open in firefox, uc browser etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I want that my website only open in chrome browser.
It should not open in any other browser like uc browser ,firefox etc.

Comment: But _why_? This sounds like an XY-Problem.

Comment: [Detect browser in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) and load the content using Ajax. (You can't guarantee that it works 100% as JS can be fooled/modified)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your launch function in below snippet which checks if browser is chrome or not.

```
if(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor)) {

}
```

Comment: And users of other browsers can easily spoof the user agent.

Comment: @MrLister everything can be spoofed on the website if we think that way..

Comment: That won't work, plenty of browsers which aren't Chrome include the string "Chrome" in their user-agent string **by default** because people do stupid stuff like this.